# Regex for reddit username works in Google form, but not in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following regex pattern to validate reddit usernames:

`u/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+`

The condition is to start with `u/` and only allow letters, numbers, underscores, and hyphens. This works fine on my Google form. It doesn't allow special characters anywhere in the username:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWWCv.png)

I used the same rule and sample in Python:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("u/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+")
query = "u/Name*"

if pattern.match(query) == None:
    print("It doesn't match the pattern.")
else:
    print("It matches the pattern.")
```

It returns:

```
It matches the pattern.
>>>
```

Which it shouldn't. Why does it work in one place and not the other?

Comment: I live by this tester app:  https://regex101.com/

Comment: @sparc_spread funnily enough I was using that same tester and was confused when my original expression didn't work. I just noticed the little flags icon which had multi-line $ set there, I'm guessing that was the overlooked critical bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indicate that you want to match the whole line with that pattern, add a `$` to indicate the end of line:

```
u/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$
```

`re.match` starts matching from the start, so using `^` to indicate the start of the line is not necessary here (which would be required is you were using `re.search` instead).

---

As a side note, you should make your Regex patterns raw strings to prevent Python interpreter from per-interpreting some escapes:

```
re.compile(r"u/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$")
```

---

Also, `None` is a singleton in Python, so you should use the identity (`is`) check, not equality check (`==`):

```
if pattern.match(query) is None:
```

Or better as `None` is falsey:

```
if not pattern.match(query):
```

Comment: Got it, thank you! Any idea why the Google form didn't need this? Would I need to update my Google form's regex too, or should I leave it be?

Comment: @Sidewinder Sorry, I'm not familiar with Google form Regex. A wild guess is that it automatically matches the whole strings i.e. put `^` and `$` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use `re.fullmatch` That's what google forms does:

re.match:

> re.match = match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>       Try to apply the pattern at the **start** of the string, returning
>       a match object, or None if no match was found.

re.fullmatch:

> re.fullmatch = fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0)
>       Try to apply the pattern to **all** of the string, returning
>       a match object, or None if no match was found.

Comment: Cool, that explains the difference in how Google forms handles regex in my original question. Thank you.